# Como agregar datos a una matriz en python?

Tags: python

```
lista_de_productos=[['Linea','ID','Descrpcion','     Cantidad','Precio'],
                    [1,1,'Agua de 1 litro ',100,15],
                    [2,2,'Leche 1 litro   ',100,25],
                    [3,3,'Manzana         ',100,5],
                    [4,4,'Cereal          ',100,30],
                    [5,5,'Agua de 2 litros',100,28]]
b=''
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(5):
        b+=str(lista_de_productos[i][j])+'\t'
    print (b)
    b=''
```

¿Tengo este código donde tengo una matriz y la muestro en forma de lista, como puedo hacer que el usuario agregue productos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo si quieres agregar datos en una matriz lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente te daré un ejemplo:

```
matriz=[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
matriz.append([11,12,13,14,15])
resultado = matriz=[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]]
```

En esté primer ejemplo lo que hacemos con el método append es agregar un nuevo arreglo a nuestra matriz de esta forma el resultado de la matriz es ampliada con un arreglo nuevo.

```
matriz=[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
matriz[0].append(6)
resultado = matriz=[[1,2,3,4,5, 6], [6,7,8,9,10]]
```

En este segundo ejemplo lo que hacer es ubicar la posición de la matriz y a esa fila le agregas nueva información.

También si no lo quieres usar de esta manera puedes usar numpy con su propio método append y se veria algo así:

```
import numpy as np
arr5 = np.array([[10,20,30],[100, 200, 300]])
arr6 = np.array([[70, 80, 90],[310, 320, 330]])
newselect = np.append(arr5, arr6 , axis=1)    
print(newselect)

Solución
[[ 10  20  30  70  80  90]
 [100 200 300 310 320 330]]
```

Ya por ultimo con este último ejemplo tenemos dos arreglos y lo que haces con numpy es acomodarlos por el tamaño numérico y aparte lo que se hace básicamente es concatenar ambos arrys

Espero te sea de ayuda amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en tu código, propongo la siguiente solución:

**Supuestos:**

- El usuario quiere añadir información al listado que ya tienes con 5 filas y 5 columnas.
- El usuario conoce con anticipación cuántos productos desea agregar a la lista.

**Paso 1: Solicitamos la información al usuario**

```
tamaño_lista_de_productos = len(lista_de_productos)

numero_de_productos = int(input("¿Cuántos productos desea ingresar? "))

for i in range(numero_de_productos):
    print()
    descripcion = input("Describa el producto "+ str(i+1)+ ": ")
    print()
    cantidad = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad del producto " + str(i+1)+ ": "))
    print()
    precio = int(input("Ingrese el precio del producto " + str(i+1)+ ": "))
    print()
    lista_de_productos.append([tamaño_lista_de_productos, tamaño_lista_de_productos, descripcion, cantidad, precio])
    tamaño_lista_de_productos += 1
```

Empezamos pidiéndole al usuario el número de productos que quiere agregar ya que así definimos el número de filas que debemos añadir al listado. Para esto utilizamos la función input(), la cual se utiliza para que el usuario pueda digitar algún texto. Dado que, por default, esta función es de tipo "string" y nosotros necesitamos que el usuario nos dé un número, le decimos a Python que nos convierta lo que el usuario haya digitado en un "int" para que así lo pueda leer más adelante como un número.

Ahora bien, como necesitamos información para cada fila, hacemos un "for i in range()" que le pide al usuario la descripción del producto, la cantidad y el precio. No es necesario pedirle la información para las columnas 'Linea' y 'ID' ya que se puede deducir, usando la función len() que nos da el número de elementos en una lista.

**Paso 2: Agregamos los datos a la lista**

Para esto se necesita el método append() que añade los elementos que le indiques al final de la lista.

**Paso 3: Mostrar la lista**

```
b=''
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    for j in range(5):
        b+=str(lista_de_productos[i][j])+'\t'
    print (b)
    b=''
```

Aquí es sólo poner lo que tenías, lo único que cambia es el número de filas ya que este número aumentó cuando el usuario agregó sus nuevos productos.

**Paso 4 (Opcional): Mejorar la presentación de la lista**

En la lista inicial, para cada producto en la columna "Descripción", veo que añadiste manualmente unos espacios en blanco al final para que las columnas se vean bien alineadas. Te sugiero eliminarlos y hacer que Python los agregue automáticamente. Para eso se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
max_tamaño_descripcion = 0    
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos): 
    if len(lista_de_productos[i][2]) > max_tamaño_descripcion: 
            max_tamaño_descripcion = len(lista_de_productos[i][2])
            indice_descripcion = i
```

Primero hay que saber cuál es la fila que tiene la cadena de texto más larga en la columna "Descripción" y qué tamaño tiene esa cadena de texto. Para eso, definimos una variable en 0 ("max_tamaño_descripcion") y hacemos un "for i in range()" que revise toda la lista (en específico, que revise el elemento en la posición 2 de cada fila). Al final, la variable max_tamaño_cantidad toma como valor el número de carácteres de la cadena de texto más larga de toda la lista. La variable "indice_descripcion", por su lado, se encarga de indicarnos en qué fila se encuentra ese string más largo.

```
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    tamaño_elemento_descripcion = len(lista_de_productos[i][2])
    lista_de_productos[i][2] += " "*(len(lista_de_productos[indice_descripcion][2])-tamaño_elemento_descripcion)
```

Con lo anterior, ya podemos decirle a Python que agregue los espacios en blanco. Este "for i in range" lo que hace es medir el tamaño del string en la posición 2 de cada fila y compararlo con el tamaño del string más largo. Así, la diferencia entre estos dos es el número de espacios que se deben añadir al final del string para que, visualmente, cada elemento aparezca debajo de su respectiva columna.

Hacemos lo mismo para la siguiente columna:

```
max_tamaño_cantidad = 0    
for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos): 
    if len(str(lista_de_productos[i][3])) > max_tamaño_cantidad: 
            max_tamaño_cantidad = len(str(lista_de_productos[i][3]))
            indice_cantidad = i

for i in range(tamaño_lista_de_productos):
    tamaño_elemento_cantidad = len(str(lista_de_productos[i][3]))
    lista_de_productos[i][3]= str(lista_de_productos[i][3])
    lista_de_productos[i][3] += " "*(len(str(lista_de_productos[indice_cantidad][3]))-tamaño_elemento_cantidad)
```

Una vez hayas hecho esto, sólo es copiar nuevamente el código del **Paso 3** para ver cómo quedó la lista.